# How to model a database for days and time scheduling?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I have to model over a relational database the following scenario.

- Imagine you have a number (say 10.000) of persons.
- Imagine each of those person may, or may not, offer a given service inside a timespan of a given day. Let's call these services "Answer phone", "Answer email", and "Answer SMS".
- I have 48 timespans a day (00:00 - 00:30, 00:30 - 01:00, 01:00 - 01:30, etc.)
- I have to schedule 7 week days (1 to 7)
- Each service can be overlapped to another.

I'm currently thinking about a structure like this:

```
id | user_id | day | t00 | t05 | t10 | [... more timespans ...] | service_type
x    001       1     1     1     0     ...                        'answer_phone'
y    001       1     1     1     1     ...                        'answer_email'
z    002       1     0     0     1     ...                        'answer_phone'
```

And so on. About the t* columns:

- every t* column is a boolean value
- t00 means "service is ON from 00:00 to 00:29"
- t05 means "service is ON from 00:30 to 00:59"
- t10 means "service is ON from 01:00 to 01:29"

and so on. So, at row "x" i've modeled that

> user 001 will answer phone between 00:00 and 00:59, while answering
>   emails from 00:00 to 01:29 on Monday.

After thinkin about for a while, this approach seems to be enough straightforward, but i fear it will suffer performance and disk space issues when dealing with thousands of users.

Infact, for 10k users, i would have (10k * how_many_services * 7days) rows, which means 210.000 records. Not that much, but users may grow, or new services may be added.

Can you suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible design.  It's not normalized at all.

I would imagine there's a 1:many relationship between a user and their activity schedules.  I'd model it that way.

If you don't know what normal forms are and why they're important, you shouldn't be doing relational modeling.  Get someone who understands it to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would have separate tables for TIMES, SERVICES, USERS and ACTIONS.

TIMES would contain just the time splits (including a textual description of the time period)
SERVICES would have the service types such as answer_phone, answer_email etc. This allows for easy future expansion.
USERS would have any info on the users of the system. Such as userID, name, department, whatever.
The ACTIONS table would be for linking all the above tables together using foreign keys.

An entry in the actions table would have its own primary key, user_FK, time_FK, service_FK.

Comment: Thank you. I've thought about this ofc, but since each entity has no relevance in other application context, i discarded it because i would need more disk space (more overhead in each table) and i would need to join 3 tables each time i need a value so, each read would have been heavier. Why would you prefer this solution?

Comment: But the way you currently have things designed you have a lot of duplicate information being stored which will inevitably lead to errors if/when you try and modify or add to your structure. What @duffymo is talking about is using tried, tested and encouraged methods to trim your design down to where there is no information duplication and your design is more robust and stable. Yes you will be reading from more tables at once but you will be reading less info. Did you test your current design to the point where you know you must streamline your reads? Sounds like premature optimisation to me.

Comment: Yeah, i'm aware about normalization. However, being aware of something doesn't mean you should blindly apply them even they're not fitting. In this case each time i read these data i need them all-at-once, there's no real need for spot-reading. I'm not saying my design is pristine-beauty or i won't be here... i'm just trying to find my balance between a neat solution and a solution that works fine

Comment: Your table as is though has so much empty, unusable space. Each row can only be used for one service_type and one day. So if a user relies to one email, one text message and one call in the same day that's 144 fields with just 3 values. Repeat this for just one user for one week and that's almost a thousand empty fields... Have you benchmarked your queries? Do you have proof that a properly normalised database would be too slow for your needs?

Comment: No proofs at this time, but i think i'm gonna benchmark these solutions soon